# Center both elements like "display: none;"

Tags: html, css

```css
.Button_Image {
            width: 40px;

            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .Button:hover .Button_Image {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .Button_Name {
            font-size: 18px; 
            color: black;
            line-height: 40px;

            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .Button:hover .Button_Name {
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="Button btn btn-success btn-block">
    <img class="Button_Image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiAkR.png">
    <span class="Button_Name">Football</span>
</a>
```

I have a button which has 2 elements inside.

1. Image of a sport
2. Name of the sport

When either of these have the css value `display: none;` the visible one is aligned to center perfectly.

But I needed to add a fade-in-out functionality, so I wasn't able to use `display` keyword. Instead I went for `opacity`.

Which resulted these 2 elements to stay side by side even if one is hidden.

How can I center these, when the other one is hidden?

This image has been captured during the transmission event: [image]

The current state is like this: [image]

But I need it like this: [image]

Comment: Show some code, without code we can only guess to what the situation is and how to assist.

Comment: @Extricate added... thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with absolute positioning of the image. Is something like this what you want?:

```css
.sportbtn {
  border: green 1px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sportimg {
  /* centered in button */
  width: 30px;
  transition: left 1s, margin-left 1s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px; /* half the image width */
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.sportname {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.sportbtn:hover .sportname {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sportbtn:hover .sportimg {
  margin-left: 0px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sportbtn">
<img class="sportimg" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/23344-200.png" />
<span class="sportname">Football</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! `%50 left` and `-50% of image width` worked! ♥